# How to read uncomitted data using JPA/EJB3 and WildFly?

Tags: jpa, jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.0, transaction-isolation

I have migrated a legacy enterprize application from EJB2.1 to JPA/EJB3 and JBoss 4.x to WildFly 17.

Throughout the application, below mentioned pattern is followed and I dont planned to modify the bad pattern because of time constraint. The default isolation level set at database is read committed.

**Pattern:
Start transaction

Save data

read data via finder methods - This requires to be read uncommitted

update something

Commit the transaction**

Read data via finder methods - This requires to be read uncommitted to read the dirty data. 
In EJB2.1 this was handled via readonly beans and I removed those while migrating the application to JPA.

Can this be achived with out modifying the code pattern used here?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using JBoss, which uses hibernate for entity manager, I unwrap the bean from JPA to hibernate session, then detached the entity from hibernate to make it kind of read only.

This entirely didn't solve the problem, I do have few objects cached in the application and whenever the read-only bean is required the cache is the first place to look for.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the isolation level at the datasource level